# C# TokenID: 1System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I'm developing in C# still and suddenly I've ran into this error. Here's the error code it's logging;

```
TokenID: 1System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
at Butterfly.HabboHotel.Rooms.RoomManager.LoadRoom(UInt32 Id) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\HabboHotel\Rooms\RoomManager.cs:line 207
at Butterfly.Messages.GameClientMessageHandler.PrepareRoomForUser(UInt32 Id, String Password, Boolean StaffRule) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\Messages\Requests\Rooms.cs:line 528
at Butterfly.Messages.GameClientMessageHandler.OpenFlat() in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\Messages\Requests\Navigator.cs:line 177
at Butterfly.Messages.StaticMessageHandlers.SharedPacketLib.OpenFlat(GameClientMessageHandler handler) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\Messages\StaticMessageHandlers\SharedPacketLib.cs:line 372
at Butterfly.Messages.StaticMessageHandlers.StaticClientMessageHandler.HandlePacket(GameClientMessageHandler handler, ClientMessage message) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\Messages\StaticMessageHandlers\StaticClientMessageHandler.cs:line 25
at Butterfly.Messages.GameClientMessageHandler.HandleRequest(ClientMessage request) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\Messages\GameClientMessageHander.cs:line 57
at Butterfly.HabboHotel.GameClients.GameClient.parser_onNewPacket(ClientMessage Message) in c:\Users\michael-webb\Desktop\BFLY\Butterfly Emulator\HabboHotel\GameClients\GameClient.cs:line 70
```

Here is the code from RoomManager.cs line 207 - loadedRooms.Add(Id, Room); Which is apart of this void;

```
   internal Room LoadRoom(UInt32 Id)
    {
        if (IsRoomLoaded(Id))
        {
            return GetRoom(Id);
        }
        try
        {
            if (loadedRooms.ContainsValue(GetRoom(Id)))
                return GetRoom(Id);
        }
        catch { }

        RoomData Data = GenerateRoomData(Id);

        if (Data == null)
            return null;

        Room Room = new Room(Data);

        //Room Room = new Room(Data.Id, Data.Name, Data.Description, Data.Type, Data.Owner, Data.Category, Data.State,
        //    Data.UsersMax, Data.ModelName, Data.CCTs, Data.Score, Data.Tags, Data.AllowPets, Data.AllowPetsEating,
        //    Data.AllowWalkthrough, Data.Hidewall, Data.Icon, Data.Password, Data.Wallpaper, Data.Floor, Data.Landscape, Data, Data.AllowRightsOverride);

        lock (roomsToAddQueue.SyncRoot)
        {
            roomsToAddQueue.Enqueue(Room);
        }


        Room.InitBots();
        Room.InitPets();

        //Logging.WriteLine("[RoomMgr] Loaded room: \"" + Room.Name + "\" (ID: " + Id + ")");
        loadedRooms.Add(Id, Room);
        return Room;
    }
```

Here is the code for Rooms.cs line 528 - Room room2 = ButterflyEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().LoadRoom(Id); - Which is apart of this void;

```
internal void PrepareRoomForUser(uint Id, string Password, bool StaffRule = false)
    {
        if (((this.Session != null) && (this.Session.GetConnection() != null)) && (this.Session.GetHabbo() != null))
        {
            this.ClearRoomLoading();
            QueuedServerMessage message = new QueuedServerMessage(this.Session.GetConnection());
            if (ButterflyEnvironment.ShutdownStarted)
            {
                this.Session.SendNotif(LanguageLocale.GetValue("shutdown.alert"));
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.Session.GetHabbo().InRoom)
                {
                    Room room = ButterflyEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().GetRoom(this.Session.GetHabbo().CurrentRoomId);
                    if (room != null)
                    {
                        room.GetRoomUserManager().RemoveUserFromRoom(this.Session, false, false);
                        this.Session.CurrentRoomUserID = -1;
                    }
                }
                Room room2 = ButterflyEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().LoadRoom(Id);
                if ((((room2 != null) && (this.Session != null)) && (this.Session.GetHabbo() != null)) && (!this.Session.GetHabbo().IsTeleporting || (this.Session.GetHabbo().TeleportingRoomID == Id)))
                {
                    this.Session.GetHabbo().LoadingRoom = Id;
                    this.CurrentLoadingRoom = room2;
                    if (this.Session.GetHabbo().SpectatorMode && (this.Session.GetHabbo().Rank < 4))
                    {
                        this.Session.GetHabbo().SpectatorMode = false;
                    }
                    if (!StaffRule)
                    {
                        IQueryAdapter adapter;
                        uint id;
                        using (adapter = ButterflyEnvironment.GetDatabaseManager().getQueryreactor())
                        {
                            adapter.setQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" + this.Session.GetHabbo().Id + "'");
                            foreach (DataRow row in adapter.getTable().Rows)
                            {
                                id = Convert.ToUInt32(row["lock_room"]);
                                string str = Convert.ToString(row["lock_rooms"]);
                                if (!((id <= 0) || str.Contains(Convert.ToString(room2.RoomId))))
                                {
                                    RoomData data = ButterflyEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().GenerateRoomData(id);
                                    this.Session.GetMessageHandler().PrepareRoomForUser(id, data.Password, true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

The rest is not to worry about. It's just other stuff, how ever I can paste it. As far as I believe, it's trying to do something with Id twice when it shouldn't be? I've never hit this error before so I'm lost on what to do. Someone able to get me going?

Comment: A lot going on here, and a lot of it seems strange. The first thing I'd like to know is what does IsRoomLoaded() look like? Also, this is multi-threaded?

Comment: internal Boolean IsRoomLoaded(UInt32 RoomId)
        {
            return loadedRooms.ContainsKey(RoomId);
        }

Comment: no reason to wrap .ContainsKey() in another method like that. It's much clearer to just call .ContainsKey()

Comment: and since the point is to return the Room object if it's there, use TryGetValue(key, out Room)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are storing the loaded rooms by id into `loadedRooms` with the statement noted by the error:

```
loadedRooms.Add(Id, Room);
```

When you are checking if the room exists in this list, you are checking by value. Unless you overrode the equals method of your Room object to compare by id, your calling the `ContainsValue` method on the `loadedRooms` with a new Room every time (since you are calling `GetRoom` to pass as a parameter).

Your code doesn't share the data type of your loadedRooms, but it seems that it is a generic Dictionary typed to the Id type and Room. If so, instead of using `ContainsValue`, try the `ContainsKey` on id alone.

```
if (loadedRooms.ContainsKey(Id))
   return GetRoom(Id);
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I like the TryGetValue(key, out value) paradigm myself

Comment: `TryGetValue` will prevent an error, but you will never match the value based on the provided code. You have to match by key or override the equals of the Room class to compare itself by Id instead of reference.

Comment: I see no reason the OP would want to compare Rooms. His first check is on Id. I would refactor this code to only check against the Id making TryGetValue perfectly valid. Instead we have a strange Room comparison with an error suppression block. This code makes no sense. Then there's a queue in the mix as well? There's a lot of strangeness going on here...

Comment: Definitely a lot of strangeness. He's comparing rooms in the first 10 lines of the `LoadRoom` method to see if he has already loaded the room to avoid regenerating the room. He seems to be using a dictionary, and because he doesn't catch his dictionary already had the key/value in it (since not comparing by dictionary key), he generates the room again and gets the error adding the dupe room into the dictionary.

Comment: @JasonW so you're suggested fix would be?

Comment: The suggested fix is the replace `if (loadedRooms.ContainsValue(GetRoom(Id)))` with `if (loadedRooms.ContainsKey(Id))`